# Adding custom properties into slx file via C# or C++

Tags: c#, matlab, simulink

I developing program which save .slx file into Vault. But during saving I need to set some custom properties into .slx file. After sucsesfull saving, second user will be able download this file and open in MATLAB and read this properties.
How can I write properties to .slx file via C# or C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest is using the normal Simulink API via the MATLAB engine  ([C++](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-matlab-engine-from-cpp-programs.html?s_tid=srchtitle)  or [COM](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-matlab-com-automation-server.html))
This requires a MATLAB installation to  be available, but ensures the Simulink file is handled with care.

If you really like to hack, de .slx is just a set of xml files, so modifying the xml directly is an option as well, but as mentioned, more a hack - and the format is not documented - as far as I am aware.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Tell me please if I use your second option and set
 ' <UserParameters>   <P Name="Custom">foo</P><P Name="Custom2">foo</P>    </UserParameters>
 into blockdiagram.xml file. How can I get all property from 'UserParameters' in MATLAB?

Comment: this should be available by: get_param(<model>, 'Custom2')

Comment: Yes it is right when user know name of properties. How will user can do this if user do not know name of property? Does MATLAB has functions to get sequence of properties name from UserParameters?